# Serving static json data to flask

Tags: python, json, flask

I have json data in demo_data.json that I'd like to bring into a Flask app. I'm receiving a 404 on the file which I've placed in the static directory, my code is below, thanks for any thoughts in advance:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask import url_for

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static/')
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
@app.route('/welcome')
def welcome():
    return render_template('welcome.html')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
    return send_from_directory('/static', 'demo_data.json')
```

Comment: Add the directory structure of your project (including the location of your json file) and the URL you are sending to Flask to request this json data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you are trying to send a file? Or show a file in an url?
I assumed the later. Notice the use of **url_for**.
This creates a link that will show your static file.

`http://127.0.0.1:5000/send` and `http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/demo_data.json`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask import url_for

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static')


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')


@app.route('/send')
def send():
    return "<a href=%s>file</a>" % url_for('static', filename='demo_data.json')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

But you also might want to check out https://github.com/cranmer/flask-d3-hello-world

Comment: Thank you I do se this is returning the data at http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/demo_data.json However I'm trying to render this data so I can use D3 and visualize it which is why I wanted it rendered on the home.html page. Should I restructure how I am going about using D3 or try and alternate method to send the file to home.html? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hmm, I think there a lot of different possibilities you have. You could also load the file using AJAX, that's what I would do.
But you also might want to check out https://github.com/cranmer/flask-d3-hello-world

Comment: This looks really relevant for what I'm doing, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You would need to define the view to send the data.

Something similar to :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask import url_for

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static/')
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
@app.route('/welcome')
def welcome():
    return render_template('welcome.html')

@app.route('data/<filename>')
def get_json(filename):
    return send_from_dir

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a trailing slash on your static_url_path. Removing the extra character resolved the issue. Also note the removed last line. The return call wasn't necessary and the function call after the return was a syntax error.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask import url_for

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static')
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
@app.route('/welcome')
def welcome():
    return render_template('welcome.html')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```